# AppleScript read content from webpage

Tags: search, applescript, html

I have been trying to learn AppleScript to solve this problem for a couple of months now.

This is my first question to Stackoverflow, so please let me know if I have posted incorreclty.

I have been doing research on this site and others, seeking to learn what I need to get this AppleScript to do what I want.
During this learning process I want to accomplish these tasks using AppleScript alone.

In the future I plan to learn Python, JAVA, shell script and more. For now I am concentrating on AppleScript.

My goal is to:

- Open a webpage.
- Do a search.
- Select one of the results.
- Search on the result page.
- Copy some text relative to the search string.
- Paste that into a text document.
- Copy something else from the result page
- Paste that into the same text document.

.

```
-- Write Document Text  
set DocText to ""

-- Look at TextEdit
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document
    -- OPENING REMARKS 
    set DocText to DocText & "Below is the content copied from a web page." & linefeed as string
end tell
-- ^ That part works


-- Look at Safari   
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    -- Open URL
    tell application "System Events"
        open location "http://www.ss42.com/toys.html"
        -- Select Search box 
        delay 1
        keystroke tab
        -- Enter search string
        delay 3
        keystroke "cat"
        -- Search
        delay 3
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
-- ^ Results of search
-- ^ That section works correctly


-- Click Link on results page. ( I don't know how to do this. )
-- Search for text string in webpage ( I don't know how to do this. )
-- Copy ContentRelitive to text string search into variable name ( I don't know how to do this. )
set ContentRelitive to "Content from webpage relative to search string. "
-- Find AdditionalStuff from page as above
-- Copy more stuff from webpage into variable name as above
set AdditionalStuff to "Additional Stuff from web page. "
-- This ^ is what I NEED to learn!!!


-- Paste all content into DocText
tell application "TextEdit"
    set DocText to DocText & linefeed & "Blank Space " & ContentRelitive & "Blank Space " & AdditionalStuff & "Blank Space " as string
    set the text of the front document to DocText & "Space Filler. " as string
    -- ^ That part works properly
end tell
```

Comment: Eek! I did something wrong in here. I did a copy and paste from Script Editor, but the formatting is nothing like I my original. I welcome advice on how to prevent that in the future too. Thank you!

Comment: Copy and paste is fine. But use the formatting buttons above. i.e for code; select the code you have pasted and then click the `{}` button.  - I have also added an update to my answer

Comment: If the below did answer your question please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not far off. Most of you code works and you only really needed to know the Safari part.

But I have adjusted the code slightly.

The *open location*  is part of the standard additions commands so you do not need to put them in a tell block of any applications.

You should always try to avoid putting code in tell blocks if they do not need to be in them. This will limit syntax and command clashes.

You should look at the Applescript dictionaries for each program you are using in the code.

Go to the window->Library menu to open the **Library** window.

This will have a list of applications. Double clicking on one will bring up it's dictionary, which will try and show you how to use commands and syntax that that individual app understands. You can add other Apps to the library by dragging them to the **Library** window. or using it's + button. Any apps that have a dictionary will be added. Ones that are not scriptable will not and you will get a message saying so.

Read Apples introduction [AppleScriptLangGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) 
And read the **StandardAdditions** dictionary in the Applescript Library

```
-- Write Document Text  
set DocText to ""



-- Look at Safari   
tell application "Safari"
    activate

end tell
open location "http://www.ss42.com/toys.html"

delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    -- Open URL
    tell application process "Safari"

        -- Select Search box 

        keystroke tab
        -- Enter search string
        delay 3
        keystroke "cat"
        -- Search
        delay 3
        keystroke return
    end tell

end tell





tell application "Safari"
    set AdditionalStuff to text of document 1
    -- This ^ is what I NEED to learn!!!
end tell

-- Paste all content into DocText
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate

    set thisDoc to make new document

    -- OPENING REMARKS 
    set ContentRelitive to "Content from webpage relative to search string. " & return & return

    set DocText to "Below is the content copied from a web page." & return & return & ContentRelitive & return & space & AdditionalStuff
    tell thisDoc
        set it's text to DocText & "Space Filler. "
    end tell

end tell
```

---

You can also cut a lot of the code out by opening and submitting the search page directly.

This is a common trick of using the results pages URL as your starting url and inserting your search term.

```
set searchWord to "dog"

open location "http://www.ss42.com/5481/search.php?zoom_query=" & searchWord & "&submit=Search"

delay 3

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set AdditionalStuff to text of document 1
    -- This ^ is what I NEED to learn!!!
end tell

-- Paste all content into DocText
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set thisDoc to make new document

    -- OPENING REMARKS 
    set ContentRelitive to "Content from webpage relative to search string. " & return & return

    set DocText to "Below is the content copied from a web page." & return & return & ContentRelitive & return & space & AdditionalStuff
    tell thisDoc
        set it's text to DocText & "Space Filler. "
    end tell
end tell
```

If I remember right,  using *open location* will use the default browser

So all the code assumes that **Safari** is the default browser